# Structure ant projects

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am currently writing an ant project xml file and I am looking for some hints and tips to improve the structure and readability of the project.

```
<target name="eatnutsOnClient" >
<monkey.eatnuts clientName="${clientName}" label="${nutLabel}" />
<if><not> <equals arg1="${returnCode}" arg2="0"/> </not><then>
 <echo message="eatnuts-[${nutlabel}]_[${returnCode}]${line.separator}" file="${reachedFile}" append="true" />
</then></if>
</target>
<target name="eatnuts" depends="createClient,eatnutsOnClient,destroyClient"/>
```

In order to manage the return codes I would like to have the possibility to replace the full if section that I need to replicate over quite some targets by a sort of function which I can call to handle the returncode logic. I guess one option would be to create a target which only contains the if section and add it to the depend list of each task? Are there better ways?

Answer (score 1):

An [Ant `<macrodef>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) provides a function-like way to share code:

```
<project name="ant-macrodef-echo" default="run">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />

    <macrodef name="echo-macrodef">
        <attribute name="returnCode"/>
        <sequential>
            <if>
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="@{returnCode}" arg2="0"/>
                </not>
                <then>
                    <echo message="@{returnCode}" />
                </then>
            </if>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="run">
        <echo-macrodef returnCode="42"/>
        <echo-macrodef returnCode="0"/>
        <echo-macrodef returnCode="-9"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Results:

```
run:
   [echo] 42
   [echo] -9
```